# Accuracy on Validation and Test set, Overfit?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, overfitting, f1score

Just a quick question: I am building an ML model right now, however, I am receiving very similar (72.2 and 72.4 for example)% for both Accuracy and F1-Score on my Validation Dataset and my unseen Test Dataset, respectively. This is occurring on most of the baseline models I have produced for my problem right now.

Is this showing that my model is completely overfitting or just acting completely random and getting lucky?

Thanks

Comment: To check if your model is overfitting you will have to compare against the performance on the training set. Do you find performance metrics on the train set significantly higher than the out of sample test sets?

Comment: Performance is extremely similar which is worrying me?

Comment: Ok, try training the model on a much smaller train set. Check if that increases performance on train set and degrades performance on test set.

Comment: @JayaramIyer  The OP said the magic word _unseen_ Test Set - so your comment does not hold. He's doing the right thing

Answer (score 1):

If the training set, validation set and the unseen test set (as you put it) have the same score, but lower than you expected then the model has *not* overfitted.

An overfitted model would have higher scores for the training data at least, and depending on how you optimised the hyper parameters on the validation data but lower for the unseen test set.

The more likely outcome is that your model has *underfitted* i.e. low but consistent scores across all 3 sets of data.

Comment: This is correct: your model is too sparse/simple.  To the OP: you should end up with both (a) higher scores across the board and (b) larger disparity between test and train. You're on the right track

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer is a good one - as it mentions you're likely *underfitting*.  What type of model(s) are you using?  If for example you're using *Linear Regression* you might opt for *Polynomial* instead. Or if the latter is being used you might incorporate some *interaction* terms . Finally if these do not suffice you might consider richer models like `_splines_`